# Does changing my android app package name changes the sha1 code of my app?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to create a firebase project and at sha1 code entering phase I get an error telling me that I have already created a project under this sha code. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: Do you want to change the package that is shown in Google Play or the package in which your Java code is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the SHA1 code is derived from the keystore you use to sign your app. If you aren't specifying a keystore then by default its a debug keystore generated when you installed Studio.

How can you get rid of it? Delete the other app from firebase.